# Icinga 2 API - set service group in maintenance?

Tags: nagios

How does one fire off a web request to icinga2 to set a service group into maintenance? Documentation is tough to find.

We frequently encounter false positive alerts during deployment (due to app-spinup) and would like to be able to programattically disable checking on service groups until deployment is finished.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unified api yet (that's something we plan for 2.4 later this year). You should use the external commands for that - given that You must first fetch all servicegroup members and send a command ffor each I'd suggest using Livestatus. Details at http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/alternative-frontends#setting-up-livestatus